# New Document button

Tags: document-library, content-type

I have a document library with both my own content type and the default one (Document). When I click the "New Document" button, only one item appears in the drop-down - Document. This happens despite of the fact that all the document types are marked as "Visible in New Button" in the Document library.

Previously, this solution was installed many times on a test environment and the both items were visible. Does anyone have an idea what could be a cause of this disappearing issue?

Comment: If you add the content type to another library in the same site, does the second content type become available on the drop down?